# How to draw a dotted line with css?

Tags: html, css

How can I draw a dotted line with CSS?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

For example:

```css
hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px dotted #f00;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
before
<hr>
after
```

See also [Styling `<hr>` with CSS](http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html).

Comment: As IE 6 (can't remember for IE7) won't understand the "dotted" style, you can tell him to use "dashed" instead, using of course conditional comments to aim IE6 and no other browser.

Comment: height: 0px; works on Chrome because the borders are separate from the height.

Comment: You should understand that dotted, dashed lines can look different in many browsers. That's more related to dashed lines.

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer has a lot of cruft that is no longer required for modern browsers. I have personally tested the following CSS on all browsers as far back as IE8, and it works perfectly.

```css
hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

`border: none` must come first, to remove all the default border styling that browsers apply to `hr` tags.

Answer (score 20):

Using HTML:

```html
<div class="horizontal_dotted_line"></div>
```

and in your CSS:

```css
.horizontal_dotted_line {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted [color];
  width: [put your width here]px;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

```
<style>
    .dotted {border: 1px dotted #ff0000; border-style: none none dotted; color: #fff; background-color: #fff; }
</style>
<hr class='dotted' />
```

Answer (score 7):

This line should work for you:

```html
<hr style="border: none; border-top: 2px dotted black" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like 'border: 1px dotted black'?

[w3schools.com reference](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_border.asp)

Answer (score 4):

```css
.dotted-line {
  border-bottom: thin red dotted;
}
```

Comment: Its a dashed line, not dotted one.

Comment: Fixed. I was mixing up dotted and dashed. Plus my answer would have given you a whole border rather than a single line.

Answer (score 4):

To do this, you simple need to add a `border-top` or `border-bottom` to your `<hr/>` tag as the following:

```
<hr style="border-top: 2px dotted navy" />
```

with any line type or color you want

Answer (score 4):

You can add a dotted line using the `::after` pseudo-element.

```css
.dotted-line {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dotted-line::after {
  content: "..........................................................................................................";
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #9cbfdb;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: 3px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="dotted-line">Lorem ipsum</h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add following attribute to the element you want to have dotted line.

```
style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ff0000;"
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the solutions on here and none gave a clean 1px line. To achieve this do the following:

```css
border: none;
border-top: 1px dotted #000;
```

Alternatively:

```css
border-top: 1px dotted #000;
border-right: none;
border-bottom: none;
border-left: none;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the default `hr` border using `color: transparent`. Then add a dashed line to the top border.

```html
<hr style="border-top: 2px dashed black; color: transparent;" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I love "background-image: radial-gradient ... "

```css
h2 {position: relative}

h2:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform:  translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -60px;
  background-image: radial-gradient( ellipse, #000 2px, #000 3px, transparent 3px) ;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: 0px 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<h2>REAL CSS DOTTED LINE</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

use like this:

```
<hr style="border-bottom:dotted" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `hr` created two lines for me, one solid and one dotted.

I found that using a `div` works quite well:

```css
div {
  border-top: 1px dotted #cccccc;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 1px;
  width: 95%;
}
```

Plus, because you can make the width a percentage, it will always have some space on either side (even when you resize the window).

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way of doing it, basically your `<hr>` accepts the border-style for each side of the quadrilateral. So you can just specify it as, for the value of none being the sides of the quadrilateral and bottom of the quadrilateral.

```css
hr { border-style: dotted none none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) applies slightly different styles to `<hr>` elements. There are no guarantees about what these styles are.

Therefore, the most robust approach is to clear out the browser's styles using `all: initial`, and *then* apply the dotted border.

```css
hr {
  all: initial;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-top-style:dotted;
  border-coler: gray;
  border width: 5px;
  width:5%
}
```

Comment: A code only answer with no explanation isn't a good answer. One that is littered with spelling mistakes and errors is a worse answer. One that is attempting to do the same thing as the accepted answer from a decade and a half ago is pointless.

Comment: what is a `noen`?