# Turn straight lines into dot

Tags: html, css

I don't know if the question title is correct or not
this is what i do
[image: line]

and what i want
[image: dót]

here is my code

`<div class="item_dot --straight"></div>`

```
.item_dot {
 background: red;
 width: 10px;
 height: 100%;
 }
```

```css
.item_dot { 
  background: red; 
  width: 10px; 
  height: 100px; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="item_dot --straight"></div>
```

I just want to use CSS to change, as height increases, so does the number of dots.
If I scroll the page, these dots appear one by one

Comment: Have you thought about using  `border-radius: 50%` with equal width and height to turn your divs into dot/circle, and maybe some padding or margin for space. And for this one "...If I scroll the page, these dots appear one by one", I am quite sure you will need some js.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I have achieved based on the question.

```css
.item_dot {
  border: none;
  border-top: 3px dotted black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="item_dot --straight"></div>
```

Hope this helps, and you can also achieve similar results using `<hr> tag`
Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746491/how-to-draw-a-dotted-line-with-css)

and to achieve this

> I just want to use CSS to change, as height increases, so does the
> number of dots. If I scroll the page, these dots appear one by one

you would need to implement JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

we added just the border-left please check it.
To overcome this problem just add these styles please check this link:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/zen-aj-5djm7b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

1st way:

```
 .item_dot:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 10px;
      height: 100%;
      border-left: 4px dotted red;
      top: 0;
      bottom: auto;
      left: 0;
  }
```

or else another way is if you get height 100px then you have apply this css

```
 .item_dot {
    border-left: 4px dotted red;
    height:100px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item_dot { 
  border-left: 10px dotted red;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  height: 100px;   
}
```

```html
<div class="item_dot"></div>
```

1. Apply a dotted `border` on the left or right side of the `div`.
2. Remove the `background`, set the `border-color` instead.
3. Set the size of the border instead of setting the `width`.
4. Lastly, add `border-box` box sizing so the `div` considers the size of the border.
5. Adjust the `height` as needed.